# How to SELECT TOP 95% of the row in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a performance report based on table data.

I dont know how many rows are there in the table, I would like to have Top 95% (Percent) of the rows based on some where condition.

Table Structure -

Column Name -  **txid , start_time, end_time**

For my Performance report I need to get the average of end_time - start_time. The common value of (end_time - start_time) ranges from 100ms to 1 sec.
However there are few transaction (less than 2% ) that took around 100-2K sec due to some or the other technical error. 
I want to avoid those rows to get a fair average report. Including those rows in my Report raises a huge concern.

Comment: Please indicate the columns in your table.

Comment: @JosephDoggie I have added the details. Apologies for the late response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery.  I would just go for `row_number()` and `count(*)`, although other window functions such as `ntile()`, `percentile_cont()`, and `percentile_disc()` could be used for this purpose:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by <ordering col>) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
      where . . .
     ) t
where seqnum <= 0.95 * cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a table TABLE with a field id:

```
select top (
(select count(Id) FROM [TABLE])*95/100
) id FROM [TABLE]
```

Comment: There is no `TOP` in Postgres (or SQL)

Answer (score -1):

In TSQL:

```
DECLARE @ourCount as Int
  DECLARE @topNinetyFive as Int

  Select @ourCount = count(1)  FROM [ourDatabase].[dbo].[ourTable]
  Set @topNinetyFive = round(0.95 * @ourCount, 0)

  Select TOP (@topNinetyFive)  *  FROM [ourDatabase].[dbo].[ourTable]
```

-- NOTE:  a more meaningful criteria could be based on one of the columns with a 'where' clause

Comment: This is neither valid standard SQL, nor  valid for Postgres

Comment: It is valid TSQL

Comment: But the question isn't about T-SQL

Comment: Someday a TSQL-developer will be glad that this is here.

Comment: Why would a T-SQL Developer look through questions tagged with [tag:postgresql]?

Comment: from Google (e.g. how to find top rows and so forth)